# Dot Product Maximization with Condition

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S = \lbrace{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\space |\space \lVert{x\rVert} = 1 \space \wedge\space x^T\cdot 1 = 0\rbrace}$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$. We wish to find,

\begin{equation}
\underset{x\in S}{\operatorname{argmax}} a^T\cdot x
\end{equation}

It is well known that $a^T\cdot x$ is maximized when $x$ is parallel to $a$.

Comment: What is $x^T \cdot 1$?

Comment: Try Lagrange multipliers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Lagrange Multipliers. We want to maximize
$$f(x) = a^Tx.$$
subject to the constraint
$$g(x) = (|x|^2, 1^T x) = 0.$$
Set $$Df(x) = \Lambda Dg(x)$$
$$g(x) = 0$$
and solve for $\Lambda$ and $x$. The system is
$$a = \lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 1,$$
$$|x|^2 = 1,$$
$$1^T x = 0.$$
Multiply the first equation to get
$$\lambda_2 = \frac{1^T a}{1^T 1}$$
$$\lambda_1x = (I - \frac{1 1^T}{1^T 1})a$$
so
$$x = \pm \frac{(I - \frac{1 1^T}{1^T 1})a}{|(I - \frac{1 1^T}{1^T 1})a|}.$$
Take the positive solution for the maximizer. Note that this result can also be obtained by orthogonal projection onto the subspace $\{x : 1^T x = 0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a= \alpha \mathbf{1} + \bar{a}$, where $\bar{a}^\top \mathbf{1}=0$

Then $a^\top x = \bar{a}^\top x$ which is maximal for
$x = \frac{\bar{a}}{\|\bar{a}\|}$

Note that $\alpha = \sum a_i$ and $\bar{a} = a- \alpha\mathbf{1}$.